# How to test for appearance of an error message after a button click with react testing library

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, react-testing-library

Hello I am trying to test the behaviour of my react app using

- `@testing-library/react` version: 11.2.3
- `@testing-library/jest-dom` version 5.11.9

The goal is to wait for an error message after a button is clicked.
In the Browser it looks like this:

1. [site before login button pressed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivjc8.png)
2. [site right after button pressed with loading indicator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dUIh.png)
3. [site with error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBnC9.png)

The pictures display what happens when a user trys to log in and fails. First the credentials are put in, then the button is pressed, then the login button changes its text to a loading message, then an error message is shown within a container. The content of the error message is "Email oder Passwort sind falsch.". How do I get a jest test to wait for the appearance of the error message and actually check if it is correct:

Here is what I tried so far:

```
import { ROUTES } from "@company/app/features";
import {
  fireEvent,
  MockedRouter,
  render,
  screen,
  waitFor,
} from "@company/test-utils";
import { tr } from "@company/utils/i18n";
import { NextRouter } from "next/router";
import { LoginPage } from "./Login.stories";

describe("Login", () => {
  it("Loads Login and causes an error", async () => {
    const router: Partial<NextRouter> = {
      pathname: "/login",
      push: jest.fn(),
    };
    render(
      <MockedRouter router={router}>
        <LoginPage />
      </MockedRouter>
    );

    await screen.findByText(tr.LOGIN.TITLE);
    await screen.findByText(tr.LOGIN.BTN_LOGIN);

    const email = screen.getByPlaceholderText(tr.LOGIN.PLACEHOLDER_EMAIL);
    const password = screen.getByPlaceholderText(tr.LOGIN.PLACEHOLDER_PASSWORD);

    fireEvent.input(email, { target: { value: "info@abc.de" } });
    fireEvent.input(password, { target: { value: "wrong" } });

    const btn = screen.getByRole("button", { name: "Login" });
    fireEvent.click(btn);

    await waitFor(() => {
      screen.findAllByText("Email oder Passwort sind falsch.");
    });
  });
});
```

So as you can see I am trying to use the **waitFor** function to wait for the appearance of the error message. The problem is that this will lead to the test **passing everytime** even if I change the function to something like this:

```
await waitFor(() => {
  screen.findAllByText("Random Random Random Random")
})
```

I am also getting this warning:

```
A worker process has failed to exit gracefully and has been force exited. This is likely caused by 
tests leaking due to improper teardown. Try running with --detectOpenHandles to find leaks.
```

Running again with --detectOpenHandles only removes the warning. The behaviour stays the same

I looked into the docs of the react testing library and found this https://testing-library.com/docs/guide-disappearance

I tried applying it to my solution like this:

```
await waitFor(() => {
  expect(getByText("Email oder Passwort sind falsch.")).toBeInTheDocument()
})
```

But now the test fails and I get this error message:

```
TypeError: Expected container to be an Element, a Document or a DocumentFragment but got string.
```

I also tried it without the wait for and just using the following after fireEvent:

```
await screen.findAllByText("Email oder Passwort sind falsch.")
```

With this the test will also not pass I think because it does not wait long enough. I get the following error message:

```
TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an element with the text: Email oder Passwort sind 
falsch.. This could be because the text is broken up by multiple elements. In this case, you can 
provide a function for your text matcher to make your matcher more flexible.
```

I also tried it using this right after fireEvent:

```
expect(await screen.findAllByText("Email oder Passwort sind falsch.").toBeInTheDocument()
```

The Error message is the same as the one right above. The test also fails.

Did anyone have a similar problem and knows a solution?
I simply want the test to wait and look until it finds the text.
Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't know the reason behind but if you try to make an assertion it might work. I had a similar issue this week. Try this:   await waitFor(() => {
      expect(screen.findAllByText("Email oder Passwort sind falsch.")).toBeDefined();
    });

Comment: Btw, the way I fixed it without assertion was by using the within() query

Comment: Have you tried using `expect(await screen.findByText('Email oder Passwort sind falsch.')).toBeInTheDocument();` as your assertion after the click action? What does running `screen.debug()` return after you click on the button? Do you see the error message in the DOM?

Comment: @LuisMendes535 I tried it with .toBeDefined but I get the same problem of that test passing with any string. Can you elaborate on how you used the within query?

Comment: @juliomalves I tried that too and it fails the test because the it cant find the text. The screen.debug() function tells me that the error message is not in the dom right after the button click. It takes about half a second for the request to get handled and return an error message.

Comment: How are you mocking your API requests? Are you using MSW?

Have a look on this : https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/example-intro/

Answer (score 2):

The `findBy` functions are async, but you aren't awaiting it or returning its result. Promises that are not awaited (or `.catch`) don't have anywhere to send their error, so they get surfaced all the way up to the node process as an `unhandledRejection`. So what happens is:

- the `waitFor` runs the function passed to it
- `findAllByText` returns a `Promise` that may or may not be rejected, but you don't capture it, `await` it, or `return` it, so it is discarded
- the function passed to `waitFor` will not throw an error whether the condition passes or not
- `waitFor` doesn't get a rejected promise or error, so the test completes successfully
- after the test framework has already moved on, the promise returned by `findAllByText` is rejected.

You want to surface the potentially-failing promise so that `waitFor` can observe the errors and keep trying. You could do this by either returning it:

```js
await waitFor(() => {
  return screen.findAllByText("Random Random Random Random")
})
```

Or making the inner function `async` and `await`ing it:

```js
await waitFor(async () => {
  await screen.findAllByText("Random Random Random Random")
})
```

Note that with the `expect` version, if you pass it a promise, `expect` itself returns a promise, which must then be awaited and used with [.resolves or .rejects](https://jestjs.io/docs/asynchronous#resolves--rejects). E.g.

```js
await expect(Promise.resolve(1)).resolves.toBe(1)
```

But this I mention this only because of the example above. The async utilities provided by `react-testing-library` should not need this syntax.

---

As an aside, if you're using `typescript-eslint`, there is a rule [no-floating-promises](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/no-floating-promises/) that will flag this, because an unawaited promise that has any possibility to throw is always a mistake. If it's plain JS, there is a [eslint-plugin-no-floating-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-no-floating-promise) that provides similar.

Answer (score 1):

> TypeError: Expected container to be an Element, a Document or a DocumentFragment but got string.

The error was happening because you didn't use `getByText` from the `screen`.

```
await waitFor(() => {
  expect(screen.getByText("Email oder Passwort sind falsch.")).toBeInTheDocument()
})
```

Alternatively if it fails, try using `findByText`

```
const errorEl = await screen.findByText("Email oder Passwort sind falsch.");
expect(errorEl).toBeInTheDocument();
```

If it still fails then there could be an issue with the error message not displaying itself.

If it could help use [jest-preview](https://www.jest-preview.com/) for easy debugging. Also look into your mock api for `/login` making sure that an error is being thrown for test to work.